# refactor two $.each() loops to one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object like this...

```
{  
   "tasks":[  
      {  
         "id":"task_3",
         "taskName":"Task A",
         "assignee":"Barrack Obama",
         "timeReqOptimisitic":"4",
         "timeReqNormal":"8",
         "timeReqPessimistic":"14",
         "timeUnit":"Days",
         "timeReq":"8.33",
         "positionX":493,
         "positionY":101,
         "lockStatus":"unlocked"
      }
   ],
   "milestones":[  
      {  
         "id":"task_1",
         "milestoneName":"Start",
         "positionX":149,
         "positionY":109,
         "lockStatus":"unlocked",
         "milestoneDate":"2015-04-07"
      },
      {  
         "id":"task_2",
         "milestoneName":"Finish",
         "positionX":989,
         "positionY":367,
         "lockStatus":"unlocked",
         "milestoneDate":"2015-04-22"
      }
   ],
   "connections":[  
      {  
         "connectionId":"con_10",
         "pageSourceId":"task_1",
         "pageTargetId":"task_3"
      },
      {  
         "connectionId":"con_20",
         "pageSourceId":"task_3",
         "pageTargetId":"task_2"
      }
   ]
}
```

...this is a minimal version. In practice, there are numerous items in "tasks", "milestones" and "connections".

I need to iterate through the object and determine the "id" of the "milestones" item with the lowest/earliest "milestoneDate", then identify the "connections" item that has the same value for its "pageSourceId" and return its "pageTargetId".

So in the above example:

Step 1)  Iterate through the object and determine the "id" of the "milestones" item with the lowest/earliest "milestoneDate".

`Answer: milestones.id = "task_1"`

Step 2) Identify the "connections" item that has the same value for its "pageSourceId".

`Answer: connections.pageSourceId = "task_1"`

Step 3) Return its "pageTargetId".

`Answer: "task_3"`

I have a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sruvtwre/). However, I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this without using the extremely high start date and also in one loop.

Comment: Can there be multiple `connections` with same `pageSourceId`?

Comment: No, all connections will have a unique pageSourceId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not parsing the same array on these two loops, there is no way to merge your loops.

Anyway, you can yet remove the loops to access to the arrays:

http://jsfiddle.net/gael/sruvtwre/2/

```
$.each(object.milestones, function( index, value ) {
    if(startDate > parseDate(value.milestoneDate)) {
        startDate = parseDate(value.milestoneDate);
        id = value.id
    }  
});

$.each(object.connections, function( index, value ) {
    if(id == value.pageSourceId) {
        pageTargetId = value.pageTargetId;                
    }
});
```

May be also sorting, and indexing your datas. Then you would need no loops:

Elements in milestones should be sorted, so the earliest milestones element would be milestones[0].

Elements in connections should be indexed by their pageTargetId property, so the requested element should be connections[id].

Your two loops would become:

```
var pageTargetId= object.connections[ object.milestones[0].id ].pageTargetId;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gael/sruvtwre/4/

As said in comments, sorting is not an optimal solution, even if that does not really matter for small sets.
Roughly, there is no no needs to sort all the datas, just the latest matters.

You can use [array reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), as an comparable alternative to a simple loop:

```
var latestMilestone= object.milestones.reduce(function(milestone1, milestone2){

    if( parseDate(milestone1.milestoneDate) > parseDate(milestone2.milestoneDate) )
        return milestone1;
    else
        return milestone2;

    //convert date to timestamp
    function parseDate(date) {
        var parts = date.split('-');
        return Date.UTC(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // Note: months are 0-based
    }

});
```

Comment: I indexed my connections array and am sorting the milestones array like this now... `object.milestones.sort(function(a,b) { return parseDate(a.milestoneDate) - parseDate(b.milestoneDate) } );` Thanks for the insight, it's working great.

Comment: just a little disclaimer of myself: sorting implies more computations than parsing sequencially. I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Assuming you get the `milestones.id = "task_1"` in first loop; outside the loop we can have use jQuery `grep`. As `connections` will have unique `pageSourceId`, grep will return an array with only one object.

```
var filteredData = jQuery.grep('CONNECTIONS_ARRAY', function(element, index){
     return element.pageSourceId == 'MILESTONES_ID'; // Which you get in the loop earlier
});
```

Then we can access `pageTargetId` like this:

```
if(filteredData.length){    
  filteredData[0].pageTargetId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var dates = []
, ids = []
, filtered = $.map(data.milestones, function(value, index) {
    dates.push(new Date(value.milestoneDate).getTime());
    ids.push(value.id);
    if (dates.length === data.milestones.length) {
      var id = ids[$.inArray(Math.min.apply(Math, dates), dates)]
      , res = $.grep(data.connections, function(task, key) {
        return task.pageSourceId === id
      })[0].pageTargetId;
      return res
    }
  })[0]; // `"task_3"`
```

```js
var data = {  
   "tasks":[  
      {  
         "id":"task_3",
         "taskName":"Task A",
         "assignee":"Barrack Obama",
         "timeReqOptimisitic":"4",
         "timeReqNormal":"8",
         "timeReqPessimistic":"14",
         "timeUnit":"Days",
         "timeReq":"8.33",
         "positionX":493,
         "positionY":101,
         "lockStatus":"unlocked"
      }
   ],
   "milestones":[  
      {  
         "id":"task_1",
         "milestoneName":"Start",
         "positionX":149,
         "positionY":109,
         "lockStatus":"unlocked",
         "milestoneDate":"2015-04-07"
      },
      {  
         "id":"task_2",
         "milestoneName":"Finish",
         "positionX":989,
         "positionY":367,
         "lockStatus":"unlocked",
         "milestoneDate":"2015-04-22"
      }
   ],
   "connections":[  
      {  
         "connectionId":"con_10",
         "pageSourceId":"task_1",
         "pageTargetId":"task_3"
      },
      {  
         "connectionId":"con_20",
         "pageSourceId":"task_3",
         "pageTargetId":"task_2"
      }
   ]
};

    var dates = []
    , ids = []
    , filtered = $.map(data.milestones, function(value, index) {
      dates.push(new Date(value.milestoneDate).getTime());
      ids.push(value.id);
      if (dates.length === data.milestones.length) {
        var id = ids[$.inArray(Math.min.apply(Math, dates), dates)]
        , res = $.grep(data.connections, function(task, key) {
          return task.pageSourceId === id
        })[0].pageTargetId;
        return res
      }
    })[0]; 
    document.write(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```